# Javascript: how can I get text outiside of selected text range

Tags: javascript, text, range

I know how to get the text from selected range through:

```
if (elem.getSelection) {
        sel = elem.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
             selectedText=sel.getRangeAt(0);
        }
    } else if (elem.selection) {
        selectedText=elem.selection.createRange();
    }
```

Question - how can I get the text before selected range and after?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function to do this using DOM `Range` in most browsers and `TextRange` in IE < 9.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bVpqR/

Code:

```
function getUnselectedText(containerEl) {
    var sel, range, tempRange, before = "", after = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        } else {
            range = document.createRange();
            range.collapse(true);
        }
        tempRange = document.createRange();
        tempRange.selectNodeContents(containerEl);
        tempRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
        before = tempRange.toString();

        tempRange.selectNodeContents(containerEl);
        tempRange.setStart(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
        after = tempRange.toString();

        tempRange.detach();
    } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        range = sel.createRange();
        tempRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        tempRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
        tempRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", range);
        before = tempRange.text;

        tempRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
        tempRange.setEndPoint("StartToEnd", range);
        after = tempRange.text;
    }
    return {
        before: before,
        after: after
    };
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much. Also there is a little error. All document and window should be replaced by containerEl

Comment: @TimurGafforov: The references to `document` and `window` are correct. Elements don't have `getSelection()` or `createRange()` or `selection` properties. Your original code could only work if `elem` is a `Document` node such as `document`. If you need to work with selections in another document such as an iframe then you'd need to adapt the code slightly to get the document and window objects from the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to know the string preceding the selection and the string ensuing it. Basically those two strings together will be your entire page minus your selection.

Here's a nice introduction to ranges: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, you should add validations incase selected text is in either sides:
Let us say that elem is a textbox:

```
if (elem.getSelection) {
        sel = elem.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
             selectedText=sel.getRangeAt(0);
        }
    } else if (elem.selection) {
        selectedText=elem.selection.createRange();
    }


var texts = elem.value.split(selectedText);
var before = texts[0];
var after = texts[2];
```

OR

```
var text = element.value;
var before = text.substring(0,text.indexOf(selectedText));
var after = text.replace(before + selectedtext,''); // or after = text.substring(before.length + selectedText.length);
```

Comment: The original code in the question suggests the OP is interested in selections within regular content, and that code would only work in the first place if `elem` is a `Document` object. Also, the code only applies to selections within regular content rather than text boxes or textareas. Finally, searching for the selected text within the text box's `value` is unreliable, since the selected text could easily occur more than once.

Comment: good point, thanks Tim that should be the limitation of the above sample.